# How can i Redirect customer to "Register" page if use email address and password is wrong?

Tags: magento-1.7, login, register

i am new in magento i want to redirect customer to "Register" page when customer click on 
log in button if user email address and password is not match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override this method: 
`Mage_Customer_AccountController::loginPostAction` and in `case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD` just redirect to `$this->getUrl('customer/register')`, but I don't recommend it. Sometimes users fill in a wrong password and it becomes annoying to have to click again on the login link.