# Magento 1: How to redirect to forgot password from login if email/password is wrong?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, login

Can you suggest me how to redirect to forgot password page if the user inputs wrong email/password in the login page?

I tried it app/code/local/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php

```
public function loginPostAction()
{
    if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    }

    if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    }
    $session = $this->_getSession();

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
        if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {
            try {
                $session->login($login['username'], $login['password']);
                if ($session->getCustomer()->getIsJustConfirmed()) {
                    $this->_welcomeCustomer($session->getCustomer(), true);
                }
            } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                switch ($e->getCode()) {
                    case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED:
                        $value = $this->_getHelper('customer')->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']);
                        $message = $this->_getHelper('customer')->__('This account is not confirmed. <a href="%s">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.', $value);
                        break;
                    case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD:
                        $message = $e->getMessage();
                        break;
                    default:
                        $message = $e->getMessage();
                }
                $session->addError($message);
                $session->setUsername($login['username']);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // Mage::logException($e); // PA DSS violation: this exception log can disclose customer password
            }
        } else {
            $session->addError($this->__('Login and password are required.'));
        }
    }

    $this->_loginPostRedirect();
}
```

I inserted the code to redirect: `$this->_redirect('*/*/forgotpassword');` under `case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD:`

```
public function loginPostAction()
{
    if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    }

    if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    }
    $session = $this->_getSession();

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
        if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {
            try {
                $session->login($login['username'], $login['password']);
                if ($session->getCustomer()->getIsJustConfirmed()) {
                    $this->_welcomeCustomer($session->getCustomer(), true);
                }
            } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                switch ($e->getCode()) {
                    case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED:
                        $value = $this->_getHelper('customer')->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']);
                        $message = $this->_getHelper('customer')->__('This account is not confirmed. <a href="%s">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.', $value);
                        break;
                    case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD:
                        $message = $e->getMessage();
                        $this->_redirect('*/*/forgotpassword');
                        break;
                    default:
                        $message = $e->getMessage();
                }
                $session->addError($message);
                $session->setUsername($login['username']);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // Mage::logException($e); // PA DSS violation: this exception log can disclose customer password
            }
        } else {
            $session->addError($this->__('Login and password are required.'));
        }
    }

    $this->_loginPostRedirect();
}
```

But still not working. Any suggestions?

Ref: [How can i Redirect customer to "Register" page if use email address and password is wrong?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9235/how-can-i-redirect-customer-to-register-page-if-use-email-address-and-password)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect a customer on **Forgot Your Password** page, you can set `BeforeAuthUrl` for customer session under `case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD` as below.

```
public function loginPostAction()
{
    ...

    case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD:
        $message = $e->getMessage();
        $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($this->_getHelper('customer')->getForgotPasswordUrl());
        break;

    ...
}
```

I've tested it and I hope it will work in your case as well.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!!

Comment: happy to help you..